# Questions Regarding Capabilities of Specific Libraries

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, questions

I was curious what the consensus is regarding questions on SO about a specific capability of a certain library/API/SDK.  For example:  *"Can Amazon AWS perform X in Y fashion"* type questions.  What I'm speaking of is mostly theoretical questions rather than actual code problems.  Should these types of questions be on SO or Programmers.StackExchange.com

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about more conceptual, whiteboard type of problems, I'd go with Programmers. These would be more theoretical, not usually involving actual code in the question. From the Intro to Programmers page:

> In a nutshell, Stack Overflow is for when you’re front of your compiler or editor working through code issues. **Programmers is for when you’re in front of a whiteboard** working through **higher level conceptual programming issues**.

Keep in mind though that these questions should be applicable to *all* programmers. I don't have the dance venn diagram with me, but stay away from very localized questions.